# Expected number of steps and probability

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have a problem that I am not quite sure how to solve using my elementary knowledge of probability. My question is this: suppose a friend and I are playing a game. We both start at 0 points, and whoever gets to 9 points first wins. There is no way of subtracting points. My friend has a 20% chance of scoring in each step, and I have a 15% chance of scoring in each step. What are the expected number of steps until I reach 9 points? And what is the probability that I will win? If you could show me how to derive these answers that would be great, thank you.

Comment: What is the correct answer for the expected number of steps to win this game? Do you know it? I get the answer between 25 or 26 steps.

Answer (score 2):

The general strategy is to condition on the first result of the game.

For instance, to compute the probability that you win, one introduces the probability $u(x,y)$ that you win starting from partial scores of $x$ games won by you and $y$ games won by your opponent.

Then,  for every $0\leqslant x,y\leqslant8$, $u(9,y)=1$, $u(x,9)=0$, and, $$u(x,y)=15\%\cdot u(x+1,y)+20\%\cdot u(x,y+1)+65\%\cdot u(x,y).$$ This linear system determines uniquely $u(0,0)$, the probability that you win before the game starts. Note that the system can be rewritten as
$$
7u(x,y)=3u(x+1,y)+4u(x,y+1).
$$
Can you solve this?

> What are the expected number of steps until I reach 9 points?

In which sense? How does one count the cases when you never reach 9 points because your opponent did first and the game stopped? Please explain.

**Edit:** Unless I am mistaken, considering $a=\frac37$ and $b=1-a=\frac47$, one finds
$$
u(9-i,9-j)=a^i\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}b^k{i+k-1\choose i-1},
$$
in particular,
$$
u(0,0)=\left(\frac37\right)^9\sum_{k=0}^{8}\left(\frac47\right)^k{8+k\choose 8}\approx27.3975\%.
$$
**Edit:** In the second question, it appears finally that one plays alone with probability $15\%$ of success at each step, hence the mean number of steps necessary to win $9$ times is $9$ times the mean time for the first success in a heads or tails game, thus, $9$ times $1/15\%$ (numerically, $60$).

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear in the expected number of steps; let's suppose my friend is down on their luck, and I can take as many steps as I need to get to 9 points without any competition from my friend. In that case, what would the expected number of steps be?

Also, sorry I'm a bit unfamiliar with the notation...is that a joint distribution? I don't know where to go next from where you left off, but thanks for your help so far.

Comment: There is no distribution, joint or otherwise, in my answer, simply *numbers* (as explained in the text). As regards the unclear second question: does this mean you are playing alone?

Comment: Hi, yes in the expected steps question let's suppose I was playing alone. And I'm sorry but I still don't understand how to use your response. I'm unfamiliar with how to use the notation you're using. I tried working on a formula for the expected number of steps earlier in the notation given in my class, but all I got to was PVn+1 + PVn = -1 (which could be wrong, sorry I'm still learning).

Comment: Which part of the notation is unclear? Unless I am missing something, every quantity used in my post is explicitely defined (unlike PVn, which would be... ?).

Comment: @d.k.o. Nice example of blind application of some ready-made formula... In the situation at hand, do you think one can achieve a success in 0 step? Then why do you suggest to use a distribution which puts some weight on 0?

Comment: I just don't know how to solve the linear system. As for PVn...p is the chance of me getting a point and Vn is the expected number of steps.

Comment: So we are not talking about *notation*, in the end. About solving the linear system, you might want to check that the formula in the Edit is indeed correct.

Comment: Oh gosh this is getting silly. Sorry to disappoint, but I can solve a linear system using notation I am familiar with. But like I said, I am unfamiliar with your notation. And who is d.k.o.? I don't see their name anywhere else here. What a strange site that people can edit responses and their names aren't shown. Anyways, I still don't know the answer to this question. Thanks d.k.o. or whoever it was for the response about the expected number of steps.

Comment: Silly indeed... FYI, so far, I am the only one involved in the modifications of this post, see [the revision page](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/750438/revisions). What user d.k.o. did was to post a misleading comment, to which I replied by the comment you can still read, after which d.k.o. deleted their own comment. Yes, such deletions have their disadvantages but what can you do about them? (Are you back to the "notation" thing again? I thought we agreed there was no "notation" problem here? By the way, did you try to check the formula in my post?)

Comment: No, as @Did correctly mentioned it was incorrect (I was thinking about expected number of failures before win and could not edit my previous comment after 5 mins). I just wanted to mention that in the case of one player the number of failures before win has negative binomial distribution and the expectation of total number of steps is of course $\frac{9}{1-0.85}=60$.